# Are there any good examples of document parsing in php?

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I am new to the php language.
I wanted to know about some good examples on how to parse a word document with the extension `.doc` and extract the data from the document in the `HTML` form for example matching the correct data from the document (with the extension `.doc`) and finally inserting the data in the `HTML` form like Name, Date of Birth, Email Address etc in php.
I have started doing some pattern matching using `regular expressions` but it has become very difficult to match the correct type of data and insert it in the right field.

for example:

```
preg_match('/^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z]{3}/',$mastercontent,$matches);
$name=$matches[0];
```

here **`$mastercontent`** consists of the data from the document i want to match my fields like name, date of birth etc with.
**`$name`** is the field where i am inserting the data in the form after matching it.

I was able to match the name but for other fields, it is showing an error if i use the similar method. But by using the `trim()` function in php, i am able to achieve this. But by using this function, the data becomes static and not dynamic. I needed some help with this.

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: Example for the code?

Comment: sample input along with expected output

Comment: Sample Input: k@gmail.com, so to extract the email id from a cv for example we need to match the pattern for the valid email id and then insert it in a text box with the field Email:[textbox] This is the pattern i gave to match the email address      preg_match('/^[A-Z a-z0-9_\-]+[@][A-za-z]+[.][a-z]{3}/',$mastercontent,$matches_1);

Comment: What's the result? remove `^`, if the email id was not present at the start.

Comment: I am still facing the same problem. Using this particular regex pattern or any other pattern, i am unable to match the data and the email id is in-between the document, not in the beginning. And i tried placing the email id next to the Name as my name is at the beginning. like this-> "PRAGYAPAI pragyapai@gmail.com" . Using the above regex pattern, i am getting this as my data in the text box "PRAGYAPAI pragyapai@gmail.com" .

Answer (score 0):

What is if you first look for a good library that do that work and don't reinvent the wheel?  If the lib is good you can look how they do it and get some impressions.

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord